# Mongoose find and update in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following data in mongoose

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57c910721e5197030038d8c5"
    },
    "firstname": "xyz",
    "schoolId": "ChIJI_40EALkDDkRs-2n_kQqPRA",
    "email": "test@outlook.com",
    "image_url": "cc7b0f23cea00964301ca225c6f3430a",
    "lastname": "abc",
    "rating": 1,
    "review": "Gr8",
    "voters": [
        "test@outlook.com"
    ],
    "time": {
        "$date": "2016-09-02T05:38:58.966Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57c910721e5197030038d8c4"
    },
    "firstname": "xyz",
    "schoolId": "sffsdssfsfsfdssdss",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "image_url": "cc7b0f23cea00964301ca225c6f3430a",
    "lastname": "abc",
    "rating": 1,
    "review": "Gr8",
    "voters": [
        "test@outlook.com,test@gmail.com"
    ],
    "time": {
        "$date": "2016-09-02T05:38:58.966Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

and I am using following query to updated the voters array

```
var query = { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id) };

    var update = { $addToSet: { 'voters': req.body.email } };
    var options = { upsert: false, 'new': false };

    Review.findByIdAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        res.json({ message: "Thanks :)" });
    });
```

Above query is working fine but I want if email is found in voters array then throw error message and if not simply update the voters array but $addToSet is not throwing any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$addToSet` behaviour is only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and does not affect existing duplicate elements.

**you can try it**: use `$nin` to check exist or not in `voters` and use `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
var query = { _id: req.body.id ,'voters': {$nin: [req.body.email]}};

var update = { $push: { 'voters': req.body.email } };
var options = { upsert: false, 'new': false };

Review.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  if (!doc) {
    return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Already exist voters or not found'});
  }
  return res.status(200).send({ message: "Thanks :)" });
});
```

Comment: Always  giving me this message Already exist voters or not found'